# How to use existing postgresql database on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm new to ruby on rails. Now I trying to use an existing postgresql db to build a RoR site. When I type

> rake db:schema:dump

I got a file Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "store", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "tel"
    t.string "addr"
    t.string "city"
  end

end
```

The table has attribute of

```
id:int (primary key)
name:varchar
tel:varchar
addr:varchar
city:varchar
```

How can I use Schema.rb to build a model for inserting or deleting data?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all this in class and this class should be extend by ActiveRecord::Migratio

**1:**

```
class RunAllMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

 enable_extension "plpgsql"

 def up
  create_table "store", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "tel"
    t.string "addr"
    t.string "city"
  end
 end
end
```

**2:** Open terminal and run rails console and paste that class definition

**3:**  `AllMigration.new.up`

Hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

`schema.rb` is only used when you need to create a new database based on your models (using the `rails db:create` command)

if you need to modify the schema of an existing database to add modify or remove a column or table, you need to create a migration file using the `rails generate migration` command.

For example to add a column to your Store model:

```
rails generate migration AddSurnameToStore surname:string
```

that will create a new migration file on the folder `db/migrations`:

```
class AddSurnameToStore < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :store, :surname, :string
  end
end
```

Finally the following command will apply your migration and update your schema.rb file:

```
rails db:migrate
```

All the information about migrations can be found there:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

To create the corresponding model on your application, you just need to create the corresponding file on your model folder:

```
cat app/models/store.rb
Store < ActiveRecord::Base   
end
```

And that's it! Then you can easily create new rows on your database:

```
Store.create name:'hello', tel: '+32 31 14', addr: 'my address'
```